# How to play vimeo video in android. I have tried using webview. Is there any other way to play vimeo video?

Tags: android, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

I have tried playing vimeo video using webview. But it doesn't look good, it makes the screen scrollable.
Vimeo has suggested one more way to play using native playback, but it has specific requirements to use

The basic requirements for native playback are:

1. User must be logged in.
2. User must be the owner of the video.
3. User must be PRO or higher (or the app must have the "can access owner's video files" capability).
4. Token must have the video_files scope.
   User must be the owner of the API app making the request

I don't have PRO account. How can i use native playback just to test, if all goes well then i will go for vimeo PRO

**THIS IS CODE WHICH I AM USING FOR PLAYING USING WEBVIEW**

```
 VimeoClient.getInstance().fetchNetworkContent(uri, new ModelCallback<Video>(Video.class) {
            @Override
            public void success(Video video) {
                String html = video.embed != null ? video.embed.html : null;
                if(html != null) {
                    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
                    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(VimeoError error) {

                Log.d(TAG, "failure: ");
            }
        });
    }
```

Is there any other way to play the video?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used **Exoplayer**. Exoplayer is more customizable. All you need is to extract the url link from the config link. You may use **retrofit** to extract the video url.

BASE_URL = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/"

You will need to use a get method like below:

```
@GET("{id}/{config}")
Call<JsonObject>getVideoLink(@Path("id") String id, @Path("config") String config);
```

You will get the id from video link. Example: "https://vimeo.com/123456789/"  Here the id is: 123456789 .

```
 JsonObject jsonObject = response.body();
            JsonObject req = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("request");
            JsonObject file = req.getAsJsonObject("files");
            JsonArray arr = file.getAsJsonArray("progressive");
            String url = arr.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("url").getAsString();
```

Now you can play using this **url** . Don't forget to initiate Exoplayer first.

Comment: Thanks for replying,
what do i need to provide in "config" ?

Comment: To get the video JSON you will need to hit the link . Example "https://player.vimeo.com/video/video_id/config" . You just need to pass the video_id only. Your video id could be 123455678..etc

Comment: here, we need both id and config. 

**@GET("{id}/{config}")
Call<JsonObject>getVideoLink(@Path("id") String id, @Path("config") String config);**

suppose the video link is https://vimeo.com/1234567
i know id = 1234567
 but config = ?

from where do i get config ?

Comment: config =config 
If your link is  vimeo.com/1234567 then 
you will use this link : player.vimeo.com/video/1234567/config  for retrofit.

Comment: thanks, it works.
but i am wondering when would i need to use scope for accessing my private as mentioned in vimeo documentations

Comment: The cdn link changes. So this will get you the latest link all the time if you use this code.